# How to write a checkbox inside form control or form control label without label

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is the sample code, what I've done so far,

```js
<FormGroup>
    <FormControlLabel
        control={
            <Checkbox
                checked={isItemSelected}
                onChange={(event) => handleClick(event, id)}
            />}
        label
        data-testid={`checkboxId-${index}`}
    />
</FormGroup>
```

But I was unable to create a checkbox inside a `form-control` or `form-control label` without label.

Comment: Since `label` is a required property of `FormControlLabel` the best you can do is to pass an empty string to the `label` property

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
<Checkbox
    checked={isItemSelected}
    onChange={event => handleClick(event, id)}
/>
```

then there isn't any label to handle

Comment: This is mui checkbox for testing(firing event) using react testing library I need form control